# Should I unsubscribe from MockBackend connections

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine, rxjs

I didn't find answer on this question in documentation. Usually I do next

```
  backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
    connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
    // response body here
    })));
  })
```

I checked the MockBackend.connectionsArray and it looks like the new instance of backend is created for every new spec, so it shouldn't be a problem.

But sometime I get weird errors from Jasmine/Karma like "expect is called outside the expectation".

Documentation says nothing about this and don't unsubscribe from this connections Observable.

Comment: got any solution?

Comment: nope, unfortunately it's still not clear for me.